# PHP grab all subpages loop

Tags: php, loops, curl

Helol. I'm writing simple bot. Bot should rip data with curl from all pages. At the start Bot knows only url of first subpage $start. After grabbing data from first page bot have first part of data and url of next subpage to rip $rip['next']. Bot should stop working when grabbed subpage have no next url to follow $rip['next'] = null

Below code prints only first subpage data and nothing else. Did i screwed something? My newbie brain need rest. Anyone?

```
goto a;
a: //first page
$rip = rip_album_single_subpage($start);
print_r( $rip['data']);
goto b;

b: //pages
$rip = rip_album_single_subpage($rip['next']);
print_r( $rip['data']);
if($rip['next']){
    goto b;
}else{
    goto c;
}
c: //last
$rip = rip_album_single_subpage($rip['next']);
print_r( $rip['data']);
echo 'done';
```

Comment: Where is `rip_album_single_subpage` defined.

Comment: FWIW, while goto statements have a place in the world, it is a very small place. You are in danger of writing spaghetti code if you keep up this style. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful

Comment: Function rip_album_single_subpage is defined. It works fine when testing on single page. It parse html and return array with two strings per each grabbed page $rip['next'] (if exists on page) and $rip['data'] (always something)

Comment: Check that the output of your rip_album... function is what you expect.  Try calling it manually with a known good url.  PS:  last time I used goto was on a ZX81...

Comment: I'm using goto statements first time in life. Can you tell me how to code it correctly ? :P Or i should regenerate my brain by sleep...

Comment: "Check that the output of your rip_album... function is what you expect. Try calling it manually with a known good url. "

Comment: "Check that the output of your rip_album... function is what you expect. Try calling it manually with a known good url." It works fine.

Comment: Don't use GOTO - code each chunk you need to call out of order as a function, after you've slept!  Try if (strlen($rip['next'])>0) as your logic rather than if($rip['next'])

Comment: Why do you have a "c" block if it will ever execute `rip_album_single_subpage(null)`?